# If the group is Abelian, why does $(ab^{-1})=e$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If the group is Abelian, why does $(ab^{-1})=e$? 
Let $G$ be an Abelian group with identity $e$. Then $H =\{x \in G: x^{2} = e\}$

The reasoning in my textbook is that,
\begin{align}
&(ab^{-1})^{2}\\
=&(ab^{-1})(ab^{-1})\\
=&a^{2}(b^{-1})^{2}\\
=&a^{2}(b^{2})^{-1}\\
=&ee^{-1}=e\\
\end{align}
I can't seem to get how we get from step 1 to 2, using the fact that the group is Abelian $(ab=ba)$.

Comment: Is there any extra assumption about the group?

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I swear this is a corruption of the original question.

Comment: Let $G$ be an Abelian group with identity $e$. Then $H =\{x : G | x^{2} = e\}$

Comment: Are $a,b$ supposed to be in $H$? And should the question contain $(ab^{-1})^2$?

Comment: See, you did miss out an important detail.

Comment: that's pretty obvious. sorry though

Comment: I'm saying that's it's obvious that I missed an important detail.

Comment: What does $H$ have to do with the rest of the question? You introduced it but did not use it. Is the goal to show that $ab^{-1} \in H$? Are you assuming that $a,b \in H$? In any case, it's not generally true that $ab^{-1} = e$ in a abelian group. Indeed it's true if and only if $a=b$.

Comment: Do you wish to show that H is a subgroup of an abelian group? This is not clear from the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only asking the step from 1 to 2:

$$(ab^{-1})(ab^{-1})=ab^{-1}ab^{-1}=aab^{-1}b^{-1}=a^2b^{-2}$$

Comment: so, because the group is Abelian, we can commute $(b^{-1})$ and $(a)?$

Comment: Yes: abelian group = commutative group.

Answer (score 0):

$$(ab^{-1})^2 = a * b^{-1} * a * b^{-1} = a * a * b^{-1} * b^{-1} = a^2 (b^{-1})^2$$